# Why is FSEvent stream not giving me any events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, fsevents

I'm trying to monitor a directory and get notified when files are added/removed/renamed. I'm using the CDEvents Objective-C wrapper. Here's the code I'm using:

```
self.events = [[CDEvents alloc] initWithURLs:@[self.programsFolder]
                                    delegate:self
                                   onRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                        sinceEventIdentifier:kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow
                        notificationLantency:2
                     ignoreEventsFromSubDirs:NO
                                 excludeURLs:nil
                         streamCreationFlags:kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes | kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot];
```

and the delegate method:

```
- (void)URLWatcher:(CDEvents *)URLWatcher eventOccurred:(CDEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"event apparantly happened");
    // just redo everything for now
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *startMenuFiles = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:_programsFolder
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey]
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:NULL];

    NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSURL *startMenuFile in startMenuFiles) {
        if (![[startMenuFile path] hasSuffix:@".plist"])
            continue;

        [newItems addObject:[[StartMenuItem alloc] initFromFile:startMenuFile]];
    }
    self.mutableItems = newItems;
}
```

But when I create files or folders in the folder it's monitoring, nothing happens. You can see I added an `NSLog` so I'll know when an event happens. Nothing is ever logged.

What could be the problem?

If you need more context, all of the code for this project is at http://github.com/vindo-app/vindo. Look in Code > Start > StartMenu.m in Xcode.

Comment: On what thread are you invoking that initializer method?

Comment: It happens to be a thread created by an NSOperationQueue...would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @KenThomases Maybe you would know: Why does the Mac icon extraction code in winemenubuilder put the icons in /tmp?

Comment: I feel stupid now. Wrong run loop.

Comment: Regarding winemenubuilder, there's no indication in the commit history. That's just how the guy who implemented it did it. I don't know that he had much of a plan, since there's no proper thing for winemenubuilder to really do on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in initializing the FSEvents source. You have to provide a run loop to monitor for events. This code was being called from a thread other than the main thread, so `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` was not the main thread's run loop. I changed it to `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]`, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the main thread, it just has to be one that you control so that you can ensure that it persists and runs its run loop. That said, the main thread is a good choice so long as whatever work you do in response to FS events is either fast or moved to another thread.